# Spring boot thread pool executor rest template behavior in case queueCapacity is 0 is decreasing performance for a rest apis application

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor, blockingqueue

I am stuck with a strange problem and not able to find out its root cause. This is my rest template thread pool executor :

```
  connectionRequestTimeout: 60000
  connectTimeout: 60000
  socketTimeout: 60000
  responseTimeout: 60000
  connectionpoolmax: 900
  defaultMaxPerRoute: 20
  corePoolSize: 10
  maxPoolSize: 300
  queueCapacity: 0
  keepAliveSeconds: 1
  allowCoreThreadTimeOut: true
```

1) I know as the queueCapacity is 0 thread pool executor is going to create SynchronusQueue. The first issue is if I give its value positive integer value such as 50, application performance is decreasing. As per my understanding, we should only be using SynchronouseQueue in rare cases not in a spring boot rest API based application like mine.

2) Second thing is, I want to understand how SynchronousQueue works in a spring boot rest API application deployed on a server (tomcat). I know A SynchronousQueue has zero capacity so a producer blocks until a consumer is available, or a thread is created. But who consumer and producer in this case as all the requests are served by a web or application server. How does SynchronousQueue will basically work in this case?

I am checking the performance by running JMeter script on my machine. This script can handle more cases with queueCapacity 0 rather than some > 0.

I really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't set the queueCapacity explicitly otherwise, it is bound to degrade performance. Since we're limiting the incoming requests that can reside in the queue and it will be taken up once one of the thread becomes available from the fixed threadpool.

> ThreadPoolTaskExecutor has a default configuration of the core pool
>   size of 1, with unlimited max pool size and unlimited queue capacity.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html

2) In a SynchronousQueue, pairs of insert and remove operations always occur simultaneously, so the queue never actually contains anything. It passes data synchronously to other thread, it waits for the other party to take the data instead of just putting data and returning.

Read more:

1. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/06/synchronousqueue-example-in-java.html#ixzz6PFz4Akom
2. https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

I hope my answer can help you in one way.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As per your first comment, if we should not define queueCapacity explicitly then what criteria should we use to define this property at all? Should we use default values for this? Secondly,  suppose all the threads in the thread pool are busy. Now a new request comes, in case of Synchronous queue this has to wait for some other thread to be free OR it will throw an exception?

Comment: Welcome. 
queueCapacity=0 defines a bounded queue of size 0. So, if all threads are busy, new requests come in, it should ideally be queued. In your configuration, that doesn’t happen as you're setting the size to 0.

For your second question, yes, it will throw a RejectedExecutionException.

More context:
[queueCapacity](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadpooltaskexecutor-core-vs-max-poolsize),
[RejectedExecutionException](https://www.baeldung.com/java-rejectedexecutionhandler)

Comment: This article should also help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390882/threadpoolexecutor-parameter-configuration?rq=1)